# Arranging Triangles

Tags: geometry

Consider three identical equilateral triangles of fixed size in a plane that do not intersect.  Connect their centers to form a fourth triangle.  Arrange the original three triangles to produce the smallest possible fourth triangle that is equilateral.  What is its size relative to the original three?  Here is an example:

[image]

This problem came up in arranging painters triangles to support a small bowl.

Comment: Please check the source. Is the fourth triangle known to be equilateral or not? Also, it would help a lot if you shared your thoughts, and/or explained where you encountered this question?

Comment: By "do not overlap" do you mean that the *triangles* do not intersect or that their *interiors* do not intersect? By "similar" do you mean that in the Euclidean sense (which would be redundant since all equilateral triangles are similar to each other) or in the sense of congruent? Are the sizes of the three triangles fixed during the problem? What about their orientations? You have some significant editing to do before the question becomes clear.